# Why does Python return a negative timezone value?

Tags: python, time, timezone

For [time.timezone](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/time.html?highlight=time.timezone#time.timezone), the Python documentation says:

> The offset of the local (non-DST) timezone, in seconds west of UTC (negative in most of Western Europe, positive in the US, zero in the UK).

Does anybody know why it returns a negative value for most of Western Europe? These countries are in a positive offset, and not in a negative one.

Example: Brussels is in UTC+1 timezone...

Comment: I suspect a typo. Did you try what it really returns?

Comment: `UTC_Time - Brussels_Time = -1` hour. So you can get this number and sum with UTC times and get Brussels times. They could do the other way and you would just need to subtract.

Comment: If it's defined in seconds _west of UTC_, a negative value makes sense for time zones that are _east_ of UTC. That strikes me as uncommon, but the description is consistent.

Comment: I know it's consistent, but I' interested in the reason why Python is handling it this uncommon way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a Unix artefact.  Although the standard numeric description for timezones is in hours and minutes east from UTC (UTC+1 for Brussels, UTC-5 for New York, etc.) the Unix `timezone` is measured in seconds *west* from UTC.

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/tzset.html:

> The external variable `timezone` is set to the difference, in seconds, between Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and local standard time, for example:

```
TZ  timezone
EST 5*60*60
GMT 0*60*60
JST -9*60*60
MET -1*60*60
MST 7*60*60
PST 8*60*60
```

As to why Unix has it backwards, I'd guess it's a historical accident, probably because Unix was originally developed in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it will be helpful to somebody if I am elaborating this. Because:

```
import time
time.timezone
```

is definitely confusing.

If your timezone is **UTC+10**, then time.timezone => **-36000**. ie; (10hrs * 60mnts * 60 secs).
If your timezone is **UTC-10**, then time.timezone => **+36000**. ie; (10hrs * 60mnts * 60 secs).
You will not be having any doubt about 36000. But doubt will be about the sign. Why you get the sign inversely?

**Why?**
In time module, Python following unix standard of time and timezone formats. In unix they are following the above standard.

**The concept is given below:**
UNIX developer believed that 
utc time =(should be equal to)= localtime + timezone  
ie: If your local time is 21, and time.timezone is -10, then utc time = 21 + (-10) = 11

But, you know that time.time() returning utc time in python time module. This timestamp is actually retrieved from bios. 
So, if time.time() is 11 (this will be actually timestamp),
and if, time.timezone is -10 then this implies two things:

1. utc time => 11
2. and timezone => -10
   We know that, utc_time = local_time + timezone  
   **So, local_time = utc_time - timezone  => 11 - (-10) = 21**